# What does "in place of" mean?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, black-widow, black-widow-2021

In *Black Widow* (2021), group of snipers are targeting a female:

> Sniper: Firing **in place of** three. Five, four...She made us.
> Target deployed smoke.

What does "in place of" mean?
I can't understand the use of "in place of".
It is not a countdown.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two targets in the room, the courier and "collateral one". The Widow sniper is planning to fire on the primary target when she gets to three (rather than zero) so she's advising the people listening in that won't be counting the number three (e.g. since she'll be too busy firing her gun).

She obviously intends to take a second action, presumably shooting the courier, when she gets to zero.

---

The script could just as easily read

> "In a few seconds, I'll be counting down from five to zero. I would like to warn you in advance that when I get to the number three, I'll be firing my gun so I won't say "*three*". I'll also be firing again when I get to zero"